# Conectar ArduinoUno+Sim808+Firebase

Tags: firebase, arduino

Buenas Colegas hace dias que estoy tratando de conectar mi Arduino Uno a Firebase por medio del Modulo Sim 808, tengo el siguiente codigo, pero no logro insertar datos a Firebase, específicamente no he logrado la conexión. Si alguno tuviese un ejemplo mas claro seria de gran ayuda

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>)

SoftwareSerial gprsSerial(7, 8);

void setup()

{

gprsSerial.begin(19200);

Serial.begin(19200);


Serial.println("Config SIM900...");

delay(2000);

Serial.println("Done!...");

gprsSerial.flush();

Serial.flush();


// attach or detach from GPRS service 

gprsSerial.println("AT+CGATT?");

delay(100);

toSerial();



// bearer settings
gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");

delay(2000);

toSerial();



gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"Kolbi3g\"");

delay(2000);

toSerial();


// bearer settings
gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");

delay(2000);

toSerial();

}

void loop()

 {

 gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT");

 delay(2000); 

 toSerial();

 gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"https://miProyexto-c4efd.firebaseio.com\"");

 delay(2000);

 toSerial();


 // set http action type 0 = GET, 1 = POST, 2 = HEAD
 gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");

  delay(6000);

   toSerial();

 gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD");


 delay(1000);


 toSerial();

 gprsSerial.println("");

 gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPTERM");

 toSerial();

 delay(300);


 gprsSerial.println("");

 delay(10000);

 }

 void toSerial()

 {

 while(gprsSerial.available()!=0)

 {

 Serial.write(gprsSerial.read());

 }

 }
```

---

Comment: Ya intentaste primero meter el numero pin de tu SIM AT+CPIN?
SI NO TE DA "READY" NECESITARAS INGRESAR TU NUMERO PIN
AT+CPIN=XXXX

Comment: Efectivamente, ya probe el asunto del PIN, y no tengo problemas

Comment: queria saber si al fin lograste conectar el modulo al firebase?